# Is there any crossover between Rogue One and Star Wars Rebels

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, rogue-one

I've not seen Rogue One or Series 3 of Rebels yet.

Given that they are operating in broadly similar time frames there is a possibility of crossover between them.

Specifically, is there anything that originated in Rebels that made it into Rogue one?

Even if it is an Easter egg for the really observant/obsessive people.

Comment: I didn't notice anything but I haven't seen more than a couple episodes of Rebels so something may have slipped past me.

Comment: According to some stuff that I see floating around the internet, a Rogue One character will be appearing on Rebels. I have not looked farther into it as I still need to catch up on the last couple episodes Rebels, and need to go watch Rogue One still.

Answer (score 18):

Three Easter Eggs have been noted that I'm aware of:

1. The *Ghost* is seen several times as part of the Rebel fleet in the Battle of Scarif:

[image: Lower middle-left]

2. At the base on Yavin 4 just before Cassian Andor and the other Rebel soldiers volunteer to go with Jyn to Scarif, an announcement can be heard over the tannoy calling

   > General Syndulla, report to the briefing room
3. Some have reported that Chopper can be seen on Yavin base (I cannot verify this one personally).
4. (Possibly) The Hammerhead corvette that rammed the Star Destroyer at Scarif was first introduced *to the new canon* in Rebels (but there it was itself a reference to the Old Republic games, rather than being a Rebels original).

Comment: What is a tannoy?

Comment: Loudspeaker, public address system.

Comment: Googling it appears to show that it's a brand name. Is there any evidence that the loudspeaker in the movie is a Tannoy brand speaker?

Comment: It's a genericised term often used in British English where American English might use "PA". I'm British. I apologise if I used a word you don't approve of.

Comment: @Werff it is not that I don't approve of it, I just want to avoid any confusion for readers (most of whom are not British, after all), and if, technically, it's not a *Tannoy* brand loudspeaker, then that is after all an inaccuracy.

Comment: @TylerH it's no different to the widespread use of "saran wrap", "pritt stick", "sellotape", "thermos", "astroturf", and many other brand names that have become generic.

Comment: @anaximander if something has become generic, that's a different story. But clearly Tannoy is not generic.

Comment: @TylerH It is generic in the UK; I hear it used quite frequently. In general, the use of genericised brand names depends on where you are, and whether that brand ever became popular there. For example, "saran wrap" is common in the US, but is never used in the UK - over here, it's "clingfilm"; I had too look up what "saran wrap" was the first time I came across it.

Answer (score 7):

Chopper appears in the scene where one of the Yavin listeners realizes Rogue One has engaged the Imperials on Scarif ([Link to the scene directly](https://youtu.be/KTKHvDNrkys?t=60)). As he is stopped by the General, Chopper can be seen briefly on the left side.

Full video

Answer (score 4):

Yes in addition to the answers above, one character is set to appear in Rebels Season 3 when it returns in January.

Which Character spoiler:

> Saw Gerrara appears. [image]

Plot Details Spoilers:

> They (the Ghost crew) go to Geonosis, Battle droids are set to appear in these episodes. From the Rogue One Visual Guide/Dictionary explains that Saw's lungs are filled with Geonosian insecticide. Hence the breathing apparatus.

Comment: Mods, can clean this up^  Couldn't manage to get the Image in the spoiler tags- I've broken it so that it appears as a link instead of the image in case visitors don't want to be spoiled. I'm new here.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this character actually originated in _The Clone Wars_, so it's more of a continuation of his arc than a direct link between _Rebels_ and _Rogue One_.  If anything, this character's appearance in _Rogue One_ is a link between _Rogue One_ and _Clone Wars_.